# Does a DynamicMap callable always have to return the same type?

Tags: python, holoviews, pyviz

The below code makes it seem like the callable passed to a DynamicMap can not change the Element type. When changing the category widget to `B` a `Curve` element is returned instead of `Points`, but the plot is just empty. Is this behavior not supported or is there some `opts` magic that is required to make it work?

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
hv.extension('bokeh')
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))

main_category_widget = pn.widgets.Select(name='Main category', options=['A','B'], value='A')
widgets = main_category_widget

@pn.depends(selected_main_category=main_category_widget.param.value)
def get_points(selected_main_category):
    if selected_main_category == 'A':
        return hv.Points(np.random.rand(5,5)).opts(size=10, title='Points')
    else:
        return hv.Curve(np.random.rand(5,5)).opts(title='Curve')

points = hv.DynamicMap(get_points).opts(height=400, width=800)

pn.Row(widgets, points)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `hv.Overlay` as return type of `get_points()` your code is working as expected:

```py
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
import panel as pn
hv.extension('bokeh')

main_category_widget = pn.widgets.Select(name='Main category', options=['Points','Curve'], value='Points')

@pn.depends(selected_main_category=main_category_widget.param.value)
def get_points(selected_main_category):
    images = []
    if selected_main_category == 'Points':
        images.append(hv.Points(np.random.rand(5,5)).opts(size=10, title='Points'))
    else:
        images.append(hv.Curve(np.random.rand(5,5)).opts(title='Curve'))
    return hv.Overlay(images)

points = hv.DynamicMap(get_points).opts(height=400, width=800)

pn.Row(main_category_widget, points)
```

Comment: Aha, I see! Thanks! :)